# How to Extract text between a string and a character?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

I have those lines in my text file :

```
msg_wdraw[] = "whatever a sentence here,"
               "This is the second part of this text1 ."
msg_sp2million[] = "whatever a sentence here,"
                  "This is the second part of this text2."
```

I need the sentence between msg_sp2million and the period "." and print them out.

i.e ("whatever a sentence here,"
     "This is the second part of this text2.")

I tried this : `sed -n "/msg_sp2million/,/./p" filename.txt`

However, this `sed` command also returns me the value of msg_wdraw (the first variable)

I also tried `awk`, `grep,` other `sed`..... but failed eventually.
How can I fix this problem ? And Why this returns me not only the value of msg_sp2million and also the value of msg_wdraw ?

Please help @ ~ @

Comment: I see some problems with that sed command, but I can't reproduce your results; I don't get `msg_wdraw` with that command. What version of sed are you using?

Comment: em .... I am using HP-UX, Here is the version info of sed : sed0.c $Date: 2008/04/23 11:11:11 $Revision: r11.31/1 PATCH_11.31 (PHC)
         $Revision: @(#) sed R11.31_BL2008_1022_2 PATCH_11.31 PHCO_38263

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
awk '/msg_sp2million/{ split($0,a,"="); print a[length(a)]; getline; print}' file.txt
```

Match regexp, print what comes after the `=`, get next line, and print that too.

Returns:

```
 "whatever a sentence here,"
                  "This is the second part of this text2."
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried awk '/msg_sp2million/{ split($0,a,"="); print a[length(a)]; getline; print}' file.txt But It is asking for the value of a: awk Cannot read the value of a. It is an array name .... ? Should I change the "a" to something else ?

Comment: Weird, it works on my awk.. Maybe you have a different awk version? `a` is just a variable name for an array where it stores the split string. Maybe switch the `$0` and the `a`..

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to add my solution (a *POSIX-compliant* derivative of qwwqwwq's solution, referred as *qww* below) as a *comment*. So, qww's solution works, but ONLY in `GNU awk` from a certain version onward (apparently 3.1.5, see also http://awk.freeshell.org/AwkFeatureComparison).

Tip: Try

```
awk -W posix '/msg_sp2million/{ split($0,a,"="); print a[length(a)]; getline; print}' file.txt
```

in a **non-GNU** environment and you will 99% sure get an error message, e. g. about using an array in a scalar context.

The following solution should also work on a HP-UX workstation:
(well, the `-W posix` may be omitted of course, but is always invaluable while in testing stage)

```
awk -W posix '/msg_sp2million/{ amount=split($0,a,"="); print a[amount]; getline; print}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using simple awk command:

```
awk -F '= *' -v RS='.' -v ORS='."\n' '$1 ~ /msg_sp2million/ {sub(/" *\n */, "\" ", $2);
         print $2}' file
"whatever a sentence here," "This is the second part of this text2."
```